# With Statement VBA

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

I'm trying to use the With statement to make my code cleaner.

But I'm getting an error when the code try to run the ".Row" line, if my Excel file is opened in another sheet then the "Mysheet".

I need to select the entire row, so I can delete everything below it.

```
With Sheets("Mysheet")
    .Row("12:12").Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Delete
    .Rows("11:11").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to `Select` anything:

```
With Sheets("Mysheet")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Rows("12:" & lastRow).Delete
    .Rows(11).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: I see. I worked around deletermining the entire address to delete.

Answer (score 1):

### Clear Data Below

```vb
Sub ClearMySheet()
    
    Const wsName As String = "MySheet"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 11
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).UsedRange
        Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = FirstRow - .Row
        If rOffset < 0 Then Exit Sub ' used range below first row
        
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count - rOffset
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' used range above first row
        
        With .Resize(rCount).Offset(rOffset)
            .Rows(1).ClearContents
            If rCount = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data, only first row
            .Resize(rCount - 1).Offset(1).Clear
        End With
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to dive deeper into it or just play a little bit, feel free to download [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEZX54OvgQiBXSIUvyuuGjczJ1AakFXV/view?usp=sharing) from my Google Drive.